# GridQueryableCollectionViewWrapper converting my Dictionary<string,object> to Dictionary<string,string> for SfDataGrid

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I'm implementing the suggestion below to bind a Dictionary to my SfDataGrid (v 19.1451.0.54) in Xamarin Forms.

I'm setting my grid ItemsSource like this:

`grid.ItemsSource = new QueryableViewExt(rows, grid);`

Where rows is an `ObservableCollection<DynamicModel>` type based on this example: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7829/how-to-load-sfdatagrid-dynamically-with-json-data-without-poco-classes

The problem is in QueryableViewExt class. When this class gets initialized (constructor call) I see the source dictionary coming in as `Dictionary<string,object>` as expected but when I tap on my grid column to sort, when it gets to GetExpressionFunc method, I can see while debugging that source changes to `Dictionary<string,string>` for some reason and it's not sorting my integers properly.

Any ideas why the dictionary types are changing?

Class definitions:

**QueryableViewExt**:

```
public class QueryableViewExt : GridQueryableCollectionViewWrapper
{
    public QueryableViewExt(IEnumerable source, SfDataGrid grid) : base(source, grid)
    {

    }

    public override Expression> GetExpressionFunc(string propertyName, DataOperation operation = DataOperation.Default, DataReflectionMode reflectionMode = DataReflectionMode.Default)
    {
        Expression> exp = base.GetExpressionFunc(propertyName, operation, reflectionMode);
        if (exp == null)
        {
            Func func;
            func = (propertyname, record) =>
            {
                var provider = this.GetPropertyAccessProvider();
                return provider.GetValue(record, propertyName);
            };
            exp = (propertyname, record) => func(propertyName, record);
        }
        return exp;
    }
}
```

**DynamicModel**:

```
public class DynamicModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public Dictionary<string, object> data;
  
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  
        public Dictionary<string, object> Values
        {
            get
            {
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                data = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Values"));
            }
  
        }
        public DynamicModel()
        {
            this.data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out in case anyone is running into the same problem.

I grabbed the code snippet from this [Syncfusion post](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7521/how-to-create-gridtemplatecolumn-in-code-behind) to build my Grid Column Data Templates programmatically. Replacing `SfLabel` with `Label` did the trick for me. Now numeric sorting works as expected

**Original Code**:

```
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
        {
            var label = new SfLabel()
            {
                TextColor = Color.Blue,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            label.SetBinding(SfLabel.TextProperty, $"Values[{kvp.Key}]");
            return label;
         });
```

**New Code:**

```
        var dataTemplate = new DataTemplate(()=>
        {
            var label = new Label()
            {
                TextColor = Color.Blue,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, $"Values[{kvp.Key}]");
            return label;
         });
```

I asked in [this Syncfusion post](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/164498/gridqueryablecollectionviewwrapper-converting-my-dictionarystring-object-to) to see if they know the reason why this behaves different for `SfLabel`.